# Random fail to build due to a 10.jar file not being deleted

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Error:

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException:
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\Roudy
Kanaan\Documents\synkers-android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\development\debug\10.jar'.
```

A fix would be to clean the project or manually killing the "Java platform SE binary" process that's actually using that file. I don't want to clean project/manually delete file every other build and I can't find a permanent fix for this problem.

What I tried:

- Invalidate cache/restart: temporarily fixes the problem
- Clean build: temporarily fixes the problem
- Deleting the file manually: temporarily fixes the problem

This issue, if I remember correctly (Not so sure), started to happen when I updated android studio to some version (3.0 maybe) I'm not exactly sure but just trying to back trace this problem.

Comment: I have this same issue... Clean project helps, but it is waste of time. I tried many things, on two independent envs, and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

people have faced random issues after upgrading to 3.0. Mine was that i was extending with Application instead of MultiDexApplication.  I would suggest you to make a new sample application via studio 3.0 and compare the changes in the Gradle scripts files.
Also, you should :

- use implementation instead of compile.
- update the build tools.
- for once, manually remove build, .gradle, .idea folder and file and the build folder from the app folder.
- upgrade your gradle.

Try these things, It will eventually get things sorted. Let me know what resolved it, even if nothing from the above.

Comment: - implementation already being used - already on latest build tools - didn't see any difference by trying this - already on latest gradle - thank you for help

Comment: can you share your app module build.gradle ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, turns out it's because of instant run. As soon as I disabled it I no longer had this error. However I couldn't find a way to re-enable it and remove the error